# Best App to Minify Javascript code and css code

Tags: javascript, css, minify

What is the best, safe and 100% free tool to be used on doing these task?   It has been asked for many times but I want to ask those experienced user.

Comment: You're right, it has been asked and answered many times. Why do you want to ask it yet again?

Comment: I'm just confused with these bunch of tools. Sorry for asking it again. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use Google Closure Tools, it uses Rhino to intepret your code while modifying it to enusre that it still works after minification. Many free tools exists: YUI Compressor, UglifyJS, etc.

UglifyJS is also good as well, try it here http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Google Closure Tools: https://developers.google.com/closure/

Answer (score 2):

if you google minify there are many online minifiers for js - these basically all do the same thing. In terms of CSS there are similar things that will make the files files smaller. You need to be careful doing this with CSS though as you need to measure maintainability against file size - unless of course you auto minify when releasing to live. You still need to be careful as changing the css could have adverse effects to your site.

Comment: At the moment this in generally how i minify my code. I guess if you had to do a lot bulk you might want something on your system but for me i'm normally just minifying something when i finish it. Its easy to just copy and paste into my browser. Also to note you can normally find web tools for the well known minifyers like yui, and uglify.

Answer (score 2):

Try MinifyCSS, it works also for JavaScript -> http://www.minifycss.com/

There are also JSMIN (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) however it works only for JavaScript.